# Record to store union of tables

Tags: oracle, union, record

I have a Oracle query which is a union of two select queries. Now I want to put that query result into a record.I know I can use a cursor but I want to use Bulk Collect, that is why 'record'.So, how do I do that or is there any other better method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rowtype` clause to make a type based on the result set of your cursor.
You can then fetch the cursor into a Array-like variable based on that type using `bulk collect`. This way, you are independent from changes on the underlying tables.

For example:

```
declare
    cursur lCursor is
        select 'a' from dual
        union
        select 'b' from dual;
    type lCursorType is table of lCursor%rowtype indexed by pls_integer;
    lTempDataArray lCursorType;

begin
    open lCursor;
    loop
        fetch lCursor bulk collect into lTempDataArray limit 1000;
        -- put your FORALL stuff here
        exit when lTempDataArray.count < 1000;
    end loop;
    close lCursor;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample example i have given
 below i have two tables Named as course and student

**course**

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE
(
  CID    NUMBER,
  CNAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  UNIT   NUMBER
)
```

Data present in course table

```
1   ORACLE  2
2   APPS    3
```

**student**

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
  SID    NUMBER,
  SNAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  GPA    NUMBER
)
```

Data present in student table

```
1   THARUN  8
```

After applying union all between two tables rows are

```
select cid,cname,unit from course 
   union all
   select sid as cid,sname as cname,gpa as unit from student
```

above query returns following rows

```
    1   ORACLE  2
    2   APPS    3
    1   THARUN  8
```

Below pl/sql block will put that query result into a record.

```
 declare 
     TYPE customer_info_rt IS RECORD
       (
          cid    number       ,
          cname    varchar2(30),
          unit  number
       );
       rec_cinfo customer_info_rt;
       var1 number;
       begin
       select count(*) into var1 from  -- It will return count of rows  
       (
       select cid,cname,unit from course   
       union all
       select sid as cid,sname as cname,gpa as unit from student 
       );
       for i in 1..var1   -- through this loop we are copying rows from select query to record one by one 
      loop 
      select cid,cname,unit into rec_cinfo from 
      (
       select cid,cname,unit,rownum rn from 
       (
       select cid,cname,unit from course 
       union all
       select sid as cid,sname as cname,gpa as unit from student 
       )) where rn=i;
       dbms_output.put_line(rec_cinfo.cid||' '||rec_cinfo.cname||' '||rec_cinfo.unit);-- it will print all rows present in a record
       end loop;
       end;
```

Rows printed by pl/sql block

```
1 ORACLE 2
2 APPS   3
1 THARUN 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you create a view and then use that view for processing data.